# KMP algorithm with blank letter in pattern

Tags: algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt, string-algorithm

can someone suggest me how to make Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm which contains "blank letter" in pattern text?
At the input you get pattern and text, where in the pattern *?* character can stand for every single letter.

Comment: Can you please attach an example in your post?

Comment: Do u mean whitespace(ASCII 32) character  as one of the characters as in pattern- "I am" ?

Comment: If yes, then u can use entire ascii(or just additionally space as another char) for creating kmp table for pattern